# Application of Bernoulli Trials

Tags: probability

I'm working through some problems on Bernoulli trials and I stuck on this one problem.

> There are 12 subscribers to a multichannel station. Each uses the link 20% of the time during peak hours. How many channels are needed to make the link available to all the subscribers 80% of the time?
>       Solution:4

I'm using the following formula to attempt this:

$$p_{n}(k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$

p is defined as the probability of some event. n is the number of trials. The formula can be used to find the probability that some event occurs k times.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how this applies to the question.

My best guess was that n=12 (12 trials - 1 per person), k=12 (since the link has to be available to ALL subscribers) and p=0.8 (80% of the time) but that does not come out to the right answer.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you to assume that if, at some fixed time $t$, one subscriber is using the link on a channel, then no others can use that link on that channel?

Comment: @awest1 that would be corect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that $n$ subscribers are trying to connect at any particular moment. You are assuming they all act independently, so we have $p_n={12\choose n}0.2^n 0.8^{12-n}$. Calculating the first few we get $p_0=0.0687,p_1=0.2062,p_2=0.2835,p_3=0.2362$. So the probability of 0-3 subscribers all trying to connect at a particular moment is $p_0+p_1+p_2+p_3=0.7947$. Unfortunately, that is just under 80%, so three lines just misses the 80% hurdle. Calculating, we get $p_4=0.1329$, so $p_0+\dots+p_4=0.9274$. Thus with four lines we are ok 92.7% of the time. So four lines are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the (really!) clear answer. For future reference what should I look for to know to use the sum of pn instead of trying to use just 1 like I was in my question? Any tips?

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy way to do problems. You just have to try to think clearly about what is really going on.